# how to display alert controller only once when the UITextfield is tapped?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to prevent user from manipulating with their data, so when they tap on `UITextfield` an `alertController` shall be displayed only once, after they press "yes" option, then they shall be able to change data. but instead of displaying alert controller once, it keeps displaying every time I tap on `UITextfield`; how I can solve this issue.

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
       let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning !", message: "Are your sure you want to change your content? ", preferredStyle: .Alert)

           let yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Cancel) { (action) in

              }
               alert.addAction(yes)
              let no = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default) { (action) in
        }
               alert.addAction(no)
             presentViewController(alert, animated: true) {}
        }
 textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var alertWillShow = true

 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

if alertWillShow {
       alertWillShow = false

       let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning !", message: "Are your sure you want to change your content? ", preferredStyle: .Alert)

           let yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Cancel) { (action) in

              }
               alert.addAction(yes)
              let no = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default) { (action) in
        }
               alert.addAction(no)
             presentViewController(alert, animated: true) {}
        }
}
 textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: your simple trick helped me, not exact as I want, but it solved my problem.
thanks